# MVC routing error 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

What am I doing wrong?

My default /User route

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "User", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I want to separate code so I create another controller "UserProducts"

my route

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "UserProducts", // Route name
            "user/products/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "UserProducts", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I have ActionResult Index in my UserProducts controller, but however my

```
localhost/user/products
```

doesn't work:

```
Error 404 - The resource cannot be found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have them in the wrong order. The order in which you register these routes is significant, and the first mapping will override the ones after it. Put the `UserProducts` line above the one for `User`.

Comment: i didnt know that this works like css, but however i changed and again no result... any  other tip?

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato - It's actually more like the opposite of CSS. The first route pattern that matches will be the one that sticks. In CSS, it would be the last one. Do you have the `routes.MapRoute("UserProducts", ...` call first?

Comment: check my screenshot http://prntscr.com/9g29z

and as i told you, i swapped their position, still error

Comment: Because your "Default" route is mapped first. That means it will override everything after it. Remember, the first pattern that matches the URL will be the one that sticks. So if you want the one called "UserProducts" to override the others, you have to put it first. Then should be "Users", and "Default" comes last. Also, the pattern for "User" is the same as the one for "Default". It should be something like `user/{action}/{id}`, or else it's going to catch everything and "Default" will never get hit.